# Mysql: Get the ID where the percentage of certain element is the highest

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, sql-order-by, percentage

I'm new to MYSQL, and I have following table. The goal is to return the deptID with the highest percentage of engineering employees.

```
empID   empName     job         deptID  salary
68      Morris      secretary   3       23000
69      Maria       engineer    3       32000
45      Kelly       engineer    7       37000
77      Hergot      engineer    7       28000
66      Hess        technician  7       32000
92      Mays        engineer    7       45000
89      Williams    engineer    12      36000
23      Smith       programmer  13      35000
56      Herr        janitor     13      26000
```

Following is my code that doesn't work:

```
SELECT  deptID
FROM Employee
WHERE job = 'engineer'
GROUP BY deptID 
order by (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM employee WHERE job='engineer')/count(*) DESC
```

A desired output would be:

```
deptID
12
```

Since for deptID 12, it has only one engineer out of one employee, which has the highest percentage of engineer.

Thanks in advance for your help.

I think this is the solution. Thanks for answering.

```
SELECT 
    deptID, SUM(job = 'engineer') / COUNT(*) AS perc
FROM
    Employee
GROUP BY deptID
ORDER BY perc DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a piece of the puzzle...

```
SELECT deptid
     , SUM(job = '?')/?????(*) * 100 pct 
  FROM my_table 
 GROUP BY ??;
```

Assuming there are no ties then we're just about done, otherwise there's another step involved

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It worked really well.  But could you explain why COUNT(*)  is not counting all the rows in my_table,  instead it counted number of rolls respect to each deptID?

Comment: Because of the GROUP BY clause